# Workflow- Design organization chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, workflow

I'm still at the conceptual phase of the ASP.net application that I'm creating. I would like to get some ideas on how to create a toolbox that will allow the client to design their own organization chart whilst using the application.

I basically want the Administrator (app user) to design a chart that will determine a set of rules. A sort of workflow designing but at the front end of the application.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to create a web version of Microsoft Visio?

Comment: I sort of do, I want the user to design their own chart. The diagram will conduct a set of rules " behavior" that the app will follow. Example: Admin will design that after a simple user connects to the app they can access the form1 instead of form2. Or if a user is younger than 18 they cannot access form3 and 4.